# Autofill Textbox in Userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a userform and I want to check if a particular giftcard is present in the database or not and if found I would like to pull the values into the relevant textboxes.

I'm using the code below. This code checks for a valid gift-card (this part works).

1. `iRow` is the Last row in database
2. `ValueToFind` is the ID of gift-card
3. `WithType` is the Type of gift-card.

**Code:**

```
For i = 1 To iRow + 1
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ValueToFind And _
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = WithType And _
        ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then

        ...

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```

But I can't find a way to update the `Me.TXT_MONEY.Value` and `Me.TXT_DATE.Value` in the userform textboxes.

Can you help me with this code?

Comment: read this please: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208)

Comment: Too... much... text... I gave up reading, and others probably will, too. If you want help, try boiling your question down to the one problem you're experiencing. I bet you can do it in 5 lines or less.

Comment: I agree with @Jean-FrançoisCorbett here. Too much irrelevant info :) Updated the question.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Good update; I think you boiled it down pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
For i = 1 To iRow + 1
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ValueToFind And _
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = WithType And _
        ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
            TXT_MONEY.Value = ws.Cells(i, X).Value
            TXT_DATE.Value = ws.Cells(i, Y).Value
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```

Replace `X` and `Y` in the above code with the relevant column number from where you want to pick up values.

Also instead of looping, you may actually want to use `.Find`? See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) link from my blog.